# Множественное использование count в Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, count

Встала задача сделать выборку нескольких ***Count-значений*** из 2-ух таблиц базы данных. Решил сделать это с помощью лямбда-выражений. На выходе получилось следующая реализация:

```
var counts = _context.Users.Select(user => new
{
   TotalUsers = _context.Users.Count(),
   TotalDeparments = _context.Depart.Count(),
   PeopleOver20YE= _context.Users.Count(c => DateTime.Now.Year - c.YearOfBirth >= 20),
   PeopleUnder20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => DateTime.Now.Year - c.YearOfBirth < 20)
}).First();
```

Это работает, но, очевидно, реализаия плохая. Как сделать нормальную count выборку используя только лямбда-выражения?

Comment: Ну, я бы написал один plain sql запрос, в linq тут не особо можно много чего сделать. Ну вот [так разве](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53841299/5752652), но я бы подумал и если это место не является бутылочным горлышком - вполне мог бы и оставить ваш вариант, т.к. на глаз проще читается (при всей неоптимальности: 4 запроса вместо одного). А вот посмотрите как примерно будет выглядеть на Dapper ваш пример с [multiple-results](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multiple-results)

Comment: @Ak спасибо за инфомрацию! Очень помогла

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тоже самое, но без лишних запросов, только необходимые

```
var counts = new
{
    TotalUsers = _context.Users.Count(),
    TotalDeparments = _context.Depart.Count(),
    PeopleOver20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => c.YearOfBirth >= DateTime.Now.Year - 20),
    PeopleUnder20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => c.YearOfBirth < DateTime.Now.Year - 20)
};
```

Если запросить счетчики в отдельные переменные, то можно использовать только два `Users.Count`, а третий вычислить через разность.

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;//получаем заранее, где-то в начале бизнес-действия
int totalUsers = _context.Users.Count();
int totalDeparments = _context.Depart.Count();
int peopleOver20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => c.YearOfBirth >= currentYear - 20);
var counts = new
{
    TotalUsers = totalUsers,
    TotalDeparments = totalDeparments,
    PeopleOver20YE = peopleOver20YE,
    PeopleUnder20YE = totalUsers - peopleOver20YE
};
```

Comment: Да, так действительно лучше. Спасибо. Вот только большое количество обращения к контексту с count ну очень мозолит глаза. Ну, думаю, что без этого никуда.

Comment: Насколько адекватно использовать в запросе `DateTime.Now.Year`? И ещё, а если этот запрос будет исполняться в момент смены года?

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос был не об этом, но замечание вполне резонное. Я бы вынес год во внешний параметр, не привязанный к данному запросу, а, например, к моменту начала бизнес-действия, связанного с данным запросом.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошиее замечание. Действительно, такое возможно. Лучше тогда выделить под дату отдельную переменную и обращаться к ней. Обязательно учту этот момент!

Comment: @rdorn Ваш второй вариант. Можно вместо **var** использовать **int** + **Convert to int**. В данной задаче не принципиально, но так, может подскажете, в плане расхода ресурсов, какой вариант ниболее экономный: с **var** или **int**?

Comment: @Avangerson var и int в данном случае равнозначны, просто привычка. Тип для var определяется в процессе компиляции, а не исполнения.

Comment: @rdorn Поправка. Проверил. **count** приводится к типу **int**. Получается, стоит **var** заменить на **int**

Comment: Кстати, переопределение переменных тоже необязательно, если они имеют одинаковые имена. Можно код оформить так: `var counts = new
{
    totalUsers, totalDeparments, peopleOver20YE,
    PeopleUnder20YE = totalUsers - peopleOver20YE
};`

Comment: @EgorTrutnev да, можно, но лично я предпочитаю придерживаться соглашения об именовании, да и мало ли как я захочу в дальнейшем изменить имена свойств анонимного класса или использовать не анонимный, а полноценный класс, пусть даже POCO, но с другими именами свойств.

Comment: @rdorn, а linq не будет пытаться преобразовать expression в sql? В таком случае на него должны быть ограничения? Или мы с фильтром материализуем из базы всю коллекцию?

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот это уже не знаю. Мы у себя все еще по-старинке на процедурах и прямых запросах живем, да и вариантов переползти на что-то типа EF пока нет, да и вряд ли появится. По идее, если EF умный - то должен составить запрос с каунтом в селекте, а если нет, то может и всю коллекцию материализовать. Пробовать надо.

Comment: @rdorn, но переменную из замыкания он же не сможет прокинуть в запрос? А с текущим временем sql мог бы разобраться, но при условии, что EF поймёт, что это оно.

Comment: @Qwertiy в том-то и дело - если поймет. Покопаю, если что-то интересною нарою допишу.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот так вроде должен понять правильно, вся статика может быть вычислена до запроса. Но с материализацией все равно не очень понятно пока.

Comment: @Qwertiy все ок, EF корректно переносит переменную из замыкания в виде параметра запроса и запрашивает Count как SQL COUNT, ну если конечно принудительно не заставить материализовать коллекцию в массив и у него уже запрашивать длину. Правда я не понял почему SQL профайлер не видит запросы с параметрами из замыкания, а без параметров видит. Но запрос можно подсмотреть и другим способом.

Comment: @rdorn, а при этом переменную надо выносить или с `DateTime.Now` тоже нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy на GETDATE() конечно не меняет, а в остальном нормально. Но вынести получение даты действия в начало действия все же стоит, чтобы не получилось "клик" в одном году, а данные из другого.

Comment: @rdorn, т. е. он на каждой строке вычисляет дату? Сам sql с `GETDATE()` вычислил бы только один раз.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95901/discussion-between-rdorn-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, результат может сильно отличаться от используемой СУБД, вернее, от LINQ-провайдера для этой СУБД. Для SqlServer могут генерироваться одни запросы, для Oracle - другие, для каждой СУБД - свои.

Во-вторых, Entity Framework (берём, конечно, последнюю версию: 6) и Entity Framework Core тоже сильно различаются и генерируют разные sql-запросы и по разному себя ведут. EF Core известен тем, что в некоторых случаях выполняет на клиенте те запросы, которые обычный EF выполнит на сервере.

У меня нет возможности потестировать разные СУБД и версии EF. Возьму для опытов EF6 и SqlServer 2016.

---

Создадим БД используя Code First:

```
public class Departament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Departament()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int YearOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int DepartamentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Departament Departament { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Departament> Depart { get; set; }
}
```

Вставим данные:

```
using (var _context = new MyContext())
{
    var d1 = new Departament { Name = "dep1" };
    var d2 = new Departament { Name = "dep2" };
    _context.Depart.AddRange(new Departament[] { d1, d2 });

    var u1 = new User { Name = "nameA", YearOfBirth = 1991, Departament = d1 };
    var u2 = new User { Name = "nameB", YearOfBirth = 1992, Departament = d2 };
    var u3 = new User { Name = "nameC", YearOfBirth = 2001, Departament = d1 };
    var u4 = new User { Name = "nameD", YearOfBirth = 2002, Departament = d2 };
    _context.Users.AddRange(new User[] { u1, u2, u3, u4 });

    _context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine(_context.Users.Count());
    Console.WriteLine(_context.Depart.Count());
}
```

Для опытов этого достаточно.

---

Код автора из вопроса

```
using (var _context = new MyContext())
{
    _context.Database.Initialize(false);
    _context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    var counts = _context.Users.Select(user => new
    {
        TotalUsers = _context.Users.Count(),
        TotalDeparments = _context.Depart.Count(),
        PeopleOver20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => DateTime.Now.Year - c.YearOfBirth >= 20),
        PeopleUnder20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => DateTime.Now.Year - c.YearOfBirth < 20)
    })
    .First();

    Console.WriteLine(counts.TotalUsers + " " + counts.TotalDeparments + " " + counts.PeopleOver20YE + " " + counts.PeopleUnder20YE);
}
```

генерирует следующий sql:

```
SELECT
    [Limit1].[C5] AS [C1],
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C2],
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C3],
    [Limit1].[C3] AS [C4],
    [Limit1].[C4] AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1)
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1],
        [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C2],
        [GroupBy3].[A1] AS [C3],
        [GroupBy4].[A1] AS [C4],
        1 AS [C5]
        FROM     [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ) AS [GroupBy1]
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Departaments] AS [Extent3] ) AS [GroupBy2]
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent4]
            WHERE ((DATEPART (year, SysDateTime())) - [Extent4].[YearOfBirth]) >= 20 ) AS [GroupBy3]
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE ((DATEPART (year, SysDateTime())) - [Extent5].[YearOfBirth]) < 20 ) AS [GroupBy4]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Запрос с кучей соединений, но это *один* запрос. То есть будет выполнен один round trip.

---

Возьмём теперь код из ответа **rdorn**:

```
using (var _context = new MyContext())
{
    _context.Database.Initialize(false);
    _context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    var counts = new
    {
        TotalUsers = _context.Users.Count(),
        TotalDeparments = _context.Depart.Count(),
        PeopleOver20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => c.YearOfBirth >= DateTime.Now.Year - 20),
        PeopleUnder20YE = _context.Users.Count(c => c.YearOfBirth < DateTime.Now.Year - 20)
    };

    Console.WriteLine(counts.TotalUsers + " " + counts.TotalDeparments + " " + counts.PeopleOver20YE + " " + counts.PeopleUnder20YE);
}
```

Он генерирует 4 простых запроса:

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Departaments] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[YearOfBirth] >= ((DATEPART (year, SysDateTime())) - 20)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[YearOfBirth] < ((DATEPART (year, SysDateTime())) - 20)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Естественно, сам собой напрашивается второй его вариант, с вычислением одного количества на клиенте. Это будут три запроса. Однако, нам неизвестно, может у автора поле `YearOfBirth` является `nullable`?

---

Что выгоднее: один сложный запрос или несколько простых? Думаю, любой спец по БД (а я таковым не являюсь) скажет, что это зависит от многих факторов. Если запросы идут через интернет, то лучше сократить их количество. Если БД расположена под боком, в локальной сети или даже на том же компе, то, вероятно, лучше избавиться от сложного запроса.

---

Похоже, чисто linq-ом не сделать простой и эффективный запрос.
Но можно сделать его вручную.

```
using (var _context = new MyContext())
{
    _context.Database.Initialize(false);
    _context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    int year = DateTime.Now.Year - 20;

    string sql = @"
declare @users int = (select count(Id) from [dbo].[Users]);
declare @depts int = (select count(Id) from [dbo].[Departaments]);
declare @over20YE int = (select count(Id) from [dbo].[Users] where YearOfBirth >= @year);
declare @under20YE int = (select count(Id) from [dbo].[Users] where YearOfBirth < @year);
select @users as TotalUsers, @depts as TotalDepartments, @over20YE as PeopleOver20YE, @under20YE as PeopleUnder20YE;";

    var counts = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Counts>(sql, new SqlParameter("year", year)).First();

    Console.WriteLine(counts.TotalUsers + " " + counts.TotalDepartments + " " + counts.PeopleOver20YE + " " + counts.PeopleUnder20YE);
}
```

Модель для запроса:

```
public class Counts
{
    public int TotalUsers { get; set; }
    public int TotalDepartments { get; set; }
    public int PeopleOver20YE { get; set; }
    public int PeopleUnder20YE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1. Про возможность NULL в дате я как-то не подумал, хорошее замечание. Но тут еще нужно понимать бизнес-логику данного запроса, я бы например оценивал именно так как написал в ответе - даже если даты нет - считаем что меньше двадцати, во избежание так сказать.